# How to set controlsource to specific row of selected/active column?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Just a question if there's a way to define controlsource for, say, combobox value to a dynamic range where it's always corelates to the same row but selected/active column. I am trying to reuse the same UserForm to fill out similar data in a sheet, moving to the right by one column and it would be extremely helpful if control source would move along with the selection.

Kinda like

```
UserForm_Format.FilmType_ComboBox.ControlSource = Cells(3, ActiveCell.Column)
```

But this particular code doesn't work

Could someone, please, help me with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the manual of the [ControlSource property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/controlsource-property) you see that the value you can set has to be a `String`.

So this line

```
UserForm_Format.FilmType_ComboBox.ControlSource = Cells(3, ActiveCell.Column)
```

actually defaults to

```
UserForm_Format.FilmType_ComboBox.ControlSource = Cells(3, ActiveCell.Column).Value
```

what you do here is setting the `ControlSource` the value in that cell. This won't work unless that value is a valid address.

So you probably meant to do the following:

```
UserForm_Format.FilmType_ComboBox.ControlSource = Cells(3, ActiveCell.Column).Address
```

Comment: I did read that, but it wasn't helpful to me at all as it didn't explain the possible commands and strings that can be used inside the VBA editor or through executing the code. That part I had to figure out myself, not even being sure if it would work. But yes! Thatš what I wanted to achieve. Thanks!